# How to configure IP address to an Huawei AR158E interface?

Tags: command-line-interface, switch

In my work we saw one old [Huawei AR158E router](https://support.huawei.com/enterprise/en/doc/EDOC1000009848/bd5ef5e8/ar158e) gathering some dust and I'm playing now with it seeing if I can give it some new purpose...

So far I have been able to configure some VLANs and a VLANIF in Ethernet0/0/2 and works flawlessly... But I was wondering if I can configure an IP address directly to a interface, let's say Ethernet0/0/2, I was somehow related to Huawei cli but my skill levels are average at most. So I try to follow this tutorial, but I get stuck in one step and I can't configure the IP.

```
<AR-158E> system-view
[AR-158E] interface Ethernet0/0/2
[AR-158E-Ethernet0/0/2] ip address 192.168.0.15 255.255.255.0
                           ^   
Error: Unrecognized comand found at '^' position
```

When I try:

```
[AR-158E-Ethernet0/0/2] ip?
  ip IP packet
[AR-158E-Ethernet0/0/2] ip ?
                           ^ 
Error: Unrecognized comand found at '^' position
```

I guess I need to active some kind of hiden option, but I can't figure it out what it can be... How, if can be done, can I achieve to configure an IP to an interface?

For additional info:
[huawei cli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2AYf.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

Huawei AR158E in version **V200R003**, only LAN interface FE0 (Ethernet0/0/0) can be configured as a WAN interface. In other words, I can only switch the interface FE0 to a layer 3 interface. Or you can upgrade the router to ** V200R010C10**, in which all FE LAN interfaces can be configured as WAN interfaces.

Once the upgrade is completed, I should configure the command 'undo portswtich' under the interface view and then assing the IP address I want to:

```
<Huawei> system-view
[Huawei] interface ethernet 0/0/2
[Huawei-Ethernet0/0/2] undo portswitch
[Huawei-Ethernet0/0/2] ip address 10.10.10.10 24
[Huawei-Ethernet0/0/2] description This is the 2nd interface
```

---

The really hard step is make the upgrade, not because it's hard to do, but because it takes time: you need to login in the [Huawei](https://e.huawei.com/en/) enterprise site, then see if your product has support, if so ask the permission to access the locked data (by becoming a customer sending a form with your product S/N), wait for some hours (it took me nearly 24h), and then download the .cc (the actual device's OS) and even a nicely Upgrade guide.

Hope this help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

If you've used VLANs the ports are likely in switch mode. In the interface context, try `undo portswitch`, removing all VLAN and switching functionality, and putting the port in L3 routed mode.